# Add multiple FTP servers with different IPs and different ports that work simultaneously

Tags: networking, debian, ftp, proftpd

I'm using proftpd in a Debian environment.

Currently, I know I can create multiple virtual hosts with different IP addresses, and that I can change the port on which they listen. But what file should I change and which configurations should I make to have one host with an IP that listens on the standard port 21, and another that listens on another port.

Moreover, how can I create an additional host that is not anonymous.

P.S. I asked this question in Stack Overflow, but then realized that it might be more suited to this site. I have deleted the other post.

Comment: The docs say you combine the port directive with the virtualhost directive to have multiple servers on multiple ports: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_Port.html

Comment: To create a virtual host that is not anonymous, simply omit/exclude any `<Anonymous>` sections in the configuration for that virtual host.